# Including an image in a Jekyll post with custom size attribute

Tags: css, image, jekyll

In a Jekyll post I want to include an image I have in the address `images/posters/surfaces.png`.

Furthermore, I want it to have a 750px width.

I tried `<img src={images/posters/surfaces.png} alt="Poster" style="width: 750px;"/>` and  `<img src="images/posters/surfaces.png" alt="Poster" style="width: 750px;"/>` but it did not work.

What syntax should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative links lead to confusion, better use absolute URLs like:

```
 {{ "images/posters/surfaces.png" | absolute_url }}
```

Or if you won't use Jekyll in a subdirectory, just use `/images/posters/surfaces.png` (note the leading slash).

Comment: Problem: when I write ` <img src={{ "images/posters/surfaces.png" | absolute_url }} alt="Poster" style="width: 750px;"/>` instead of an image I get text with a linked URL inside.