# How to set size/rotate image in jekyll?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

How to set size of image in jekyll markdown?

```
![steam-fish-1]({{ "/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" | absolute_url }})
```

I'm using jekyll minima. Using

```
![steam-fish-1]({{ "/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" | absolute_url }} =250x)
```

from [Changing image size in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/changing-image-size-in-markdown) doesn't work. If possible, I would like to know how to rotate image as well.

Answer (score 29):

Jekyll seems to accept attribute lists. You can set the size of an image as follows:

```
![steam-fish-1](/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg){: width="250" }
```

(or use `height="250"`). The property value is in pixels, and should (according to the HTML spec) not have explicit units.

Comment: For me, this was the solution. Set a CSS id like this and then change the `width` or `max-width` per CSS.

Comment: Best solution for me adding {: width="250" } to the Markdown statement. Works fine! @Cris Luengo

Answer (score 3):

Markdown doesn't have built in support for image-sizes, so the only real solution is to use a little HTML inside your markdown. Given that, my [jekyll-image-size](https://github.com/generalui/jekyll-image-size) plugin can do the resizing you need without any CSS.

Example:

```html
<!-- template -->
{{ /assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg:img?width=250 alt='steam-fish-1' }}

<!-- output -->
<a href="/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" width='250' height='YYY' alt='steam-fish-1'>
```

(Where `YYY` is the actual, proportionally scaled height of your image.)

If you need the absolute_url filter:

```
<!-- template -->
<a 
  href={{ "/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" | absolute_url }} 
  {{ /assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg:props?width=250 }} 
  alt='steam-fish-1'
>

<!-- output -->
<a href="http://test.com/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" width='250' height='YYY' alt='steam-fish-1'>
```

For rotating your images, would it make sense to just rotate the image file itself?

Comment: It does not work for me. jekyll-image-size documentation say that you need to use `{% imagesize source:img %}`, but you use `{{ source:img }}`. Did I something miss?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to include a size/rotation attribute to a Jekyll generated HTML code (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869921/6309), see the comments)... there is always the CSS route.

See "[Resize image proportionally with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711996/6309)": you could add a CSS stylesheet to set the size of your picture. Or even [rotate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50310668/6309).

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand very well how to create a CSS file in Jekyll? If you can give more specific steps it'd be great.

Comment: @ZHU Sure, you can start with https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/

Answer (score -1):

With [jekyll-image-size](https://github.com/generalui/jekyll-image-size), should use

```
<!-- template -->
{% imagesize /assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg:img?width=250 alt='steam-fish-1' %}

<!-- output -->
<a href="assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" width='250' height='YYY' alt='steam-fish-1'>
```

Comment: This can only be done in a template, not in markdown content.

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
![Load](/blog/assets/images/blog/grpc/csharp2.png){:width="100%"}
```