Resize image in Github Pages using markdown, when the image is called with ?raw=true
I'm trying to create a webpage in Github Pages using Markdown and would like to resize an image. The original image displays nicely using:
![](Solicitadores01.png?raw=true)

The problem is that all the solutions that I have tried for the case without ?raw=true, don't appear to work for this case.
Is there a way to achieve it?

github pages uses jekyll by default. thus see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992317/how-to-set-size-rotate-image-in-jekyll
